# Retrieve a value in a xml file and use it in another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I would like to retrieve a value in a xml file and use this value in another function.

**I use:**

```
function xmlparser() {
    var xmlhttp, myvar;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.domain.net/xmlfile.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myvar = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("date")[0].textContent;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**How can I use `myvar` in another function ?
Like**

```
function test() {
    alert(myvar);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
function test(myvar) {
    alert(myvar);
}

function xmlparser()
{
    var xmlhttp, xml_build, xml_dashboard;
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.domain.net/xmlfile.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            myvar=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("date")[0].textContent;
            test(myvar);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer. But the function 'test' in a big function doing many things. I just want to use 'myvar' in 'test' before running 'test'.

Comment: When you make an AJAX request, the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function is run once the AJAX HTTP request returns.  So, the `myvar` variable is only set after the AJAX call returns (which could take a non-trivial amount of time).  You can not rely on it's value being set until after you set it in the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function.  The function that is relying on myvar (test) should only be run after the AJAX call returns and myvar is set.  You should call test inside the AJAX callback function, otherwise all bets are off as to what myvar would be set to.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That makes perfectly sense and helped me a lot. I made few changes in my code and it works.